# Find the middle of 3 numbers

Tags: ocaml

So I have a problem finding the middle number between 3 numbers. I wrote a code but I get `"Exception: Failure "int_of_string"` message. Do you have any idea why?

```
 let minimum a b c = min a (min b c)
 let maximum a b c = max a (max b c)
 let middle a b c =if a > (minimum a b c) && a < (maximum a b c) then Printf.printf "The middle is %d" a;
                    if b > (minimum a b c) && b < (maximum a b c) then Printf.printf "The middle is %d" b;
                    if c > (minimum a b c) && c < (maximum a b c) then Printf.printf "The middle is %d" c
let () = print_string "Enter x: "
let x = read_int ()
let () = print_string "Enter y: "
let y = read_int ()
let () = print_string "Enter z: "
let z = read_int ()
let mid = middle x y z;;
```

When I run it I get this:

```
let minimum a b c = min a (min b c)
let maximum a b c = max a (max b c)
let mediana a b c = if a > (minimum a b c) && a < (maximum a b c) then Printf.printf "The middle is %d" a;
                      if b > (minimum a b c) && b < (maximum a b c) then Printf.printf "The middle is %d" b;
                      if c > (minimum a b c) && c < (maximum a b c) then Printf.printf "The middle is %d" c
  let () = print_string "Enter x: "
  let x = read_int ()
  let () = print_string "Enter y: "
  let y = read_int ()
  let () = print_string "Enter z: "
  let z = read_int ()
  let mid = middle x y z;;
Enter x:
Exception: Failure "int_of_string".
#
```

Comment: We need some more context. First, you're not showing us the **exact** code that you have written. In particular, you define `minimum` but use `minim` (similarly `maxim`). Furthermore, you're not telling us what input you feed the 3 `read_int` calls with. The exception indicates that OCaml was unable to convert these inputs into integers, but if I enter e.g. `12`, `34` and `56`, **each** followed by a return (as opposed to `12 34 56` <kbd>Enter</kbd>), everything works fine.
As a side note, note that `middle` won't output anything if at least two numbers are equal.

Comment: I edited the minimum/maximum part. Do you have any idea how to make the code work right?

Comment: @OvyOvy What do you mean by "work right"? What should it do when you give it invalid input?

Comment: What do you mean by invalid input? I want it to not give that error when I run it.

Comment: @OvyOvy read the last part of my first comment: the problem you describe likely does not lie in the program itself but in the input you give to it. Since you do not provide us with said input, it's difficult for us to come up with an adequate answer. An hypothesis (again mentioned in my comment) is that you separate your numbers by a space and not a return. But there are infinitely many interactive inputs that will produce the error. That's why it is important for you to provide us with the exact input you have given. Only then will it be possible to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: The problem is that it does not let me enter values when it gives me that error.

Comment: @OvyOvy if the situation I describe in my answer below is the right one, I think you should edit your question to indicate that you're using the plain `ocaml` interpreter and make apparent the extra newline in the original source code. This might help others understanding the issue.

Comment: @Virgile I will try to rewrite the code in a new file and update.

Answer (score 2):

If I start a fresh interpreter from a Linux shell with either the `ocaml` or `utop` command and then copy/paste your first code into it, I have no trouble entering the number.

However, if somehow there is a blank line after the `;;` in your code, then the `ocaml` interpreter thinks of it as the input for `x`, and indeed directly complains that this empty line cannot be converted into a number, leading to the symptoms you describe. I'd thus advise you to be careful not to copy extraneous characters (especially newlines) when feeding the interpreter, or to switch to [`utop`](https://github.com/ocaml-community/utop), which does not exhibit this behavior and is a much nicer toplevel, with command history and autocompletion among other nice things.